# Firebase serve works but Firebase deploy gets Deployment error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I created an API with various functions in `index.js`. I am able to run them using `firebase serve` and sending HTTP requests with Postman. All my functions work, and are able to post and get to Firestore.

The problem is when I try to deploy them to production using `firebase deploy`, I get a deployment error

> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs

I am not able to figure out how to use Google cloud.

It is probably important to notice that I was using Node 8, and had my API functions correctly deployed. However, I switched to Node 10 a couple days ago, deleted the old API deploy and try to make a new deploy and I get the error mentioned. I have updated firebase tools and package json engines node 10.

Comment: The error message is suggesting that you take a look at logs.  Without seeing that, in addition to the code you're trying to deploy, there's no much we can do to help.

Comment: I tried to dowload gcloud tools, but my computer can't handle it right now (completely my fault). Also, the project doesn't appear on the Logging dashboard. I was trying to see if there is a way to see the logs

Comment: Go to firebase console hover on project overview on top left side click on project settings, Then click on service accounts tab and there you can see "generate new private key".click on that and save in your respective directory and now hit this command


$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path to service account generated file.json" firebase deploy --only functions,hosting

Answer (score -2):

Usually when I post the question in SO, I end up finding a solution shortly after. Either way, in case someone finds the same problem:

Using `firebase debug --serve` I found various logs with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

The problem is with authentication. This reminded me that to make `firebase serve` work, I added this line to admin initalize app:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(require('../../keys/myproject.sdk.json')),
});
```

I just uncomment it when I want to deploy to production, and now it works!